# Keycloak MySql Setup

Tags: mysql, wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to connect keycloak to mysql database. I followed tutorial and watched some similar youtube videos about wildfly example. I get 404 not found page instead of admin or first install page. Did I miss something?

https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-installation-and-configuration/content/v/2.0/topics/database.html

```
  <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloak</connection-url>
           <driver>mysql</driver>
           <pool>
               <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
           </pool>
           <security>
               <user-name>sa</user-name>
               <password>password</password>
           </security>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the mistake. Instead of putting jdbc jar into /modules.../keycloak/com.. like tutorial said, I put into /modules.../base/com..

Answer (score 0):

List of versions supported for the keycloak. For using keycloak with mysql db.

```
keycloak-4.5.0.Final ---> Mysql Server 5.5 -->with  mysql-connector-java-8.0.12  Mysql Workbench 6.3CE  ---->Working Properly
mysql-connector-java-5.1.42 
mysql-connector-java-6.0.4  
mysql-connector-java-6.0.6 
mysql-connector-java-8.0.11
mysql-connector-java-5.1.45 Working Properly   
mysql-connector-java-5.0.5 not working
```

keycloak-4.5.0.Final ---> Mysql Server 5.6 & Mysql Server 5.7 is not working